# MySQL using COUNT, LEFT JOIN and GROUP by returning undesired results

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, left-join

I need some help to get the desired results, which would in this case, be 7 (the number of rows in the products table that would match).

What I am instead getting is 7 rows with a count based on the the number of rows returned in the LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT count(p.id) as theCount 
            FROM products p 
            left join tablea a on p.id = a.productId 
            left join tableb b on p.id = b.productId 
            WHERE (a.col = 'val' or b.col = 'val')
group by p.id
```

If I do not group by p.id, I get back 28 rows, which is all of the rows from the LEFT JOIN.

I know it's something simple, but I can't figure it out.

Thanks.

Comment: `select count(distinct p.id)`, perhaps? Since you're pulling from two different tables, you're going to get a mismash of (p.id, a.col, b.col) being `(xxx, null, yyy)` and `(xxx, yyy, null)`.

Comment: Actually, distinct worked with no GROUP BY. If you put that as an answer, I will mark it correct. Thanks either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`select count(distinct p.id)`, perhaps? Since you're pulling from two different tables, you're going to get a mismash of `(p.id, a.col, b.col)` being `(xxx, null, yyy)` and `(xxx, yyy, null)`

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't join the one-to-many relationships if all you want is the count of `products`.

Put your filter condition in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT count(*) as theCount 
        FROM products p 
        WHERE p.id IN (
             SELECT a.productId
             FROM tablea a
             WHERE a.productId = p.id AND a.col = 'val'

             UNION

             SELECT b.productId
             FROM tableb b
             WHERE b.productId = p.id AND b.col = 'val'
        )
```

Comment: I see what you are saying, but could you elaborate on that point? The rows I want to count are the product table rows, but the data I want to match on may or may not be in the other tables. If the data is not in one of the other tables, I do not want those counted. Hopefully that makes sense.